# Having issues with multiple search strings on command line in C on linux

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to pass in multiple arguments through the command line into my C program on my linux terminal but I'm getting a Segmentation error.

This is my output:

```
$ ./a.out bar a a
you made it past opening and reading file
your file size is 7
Your count is:2
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

This is what I should get:

```
 $ ./a.out bar a a
 you made it past opening and reading file
 your file size is 7
 Your count is:2
 Your count is:2
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[] ) 
{

  /******* Open, Read, Close file**********************************/

  FILE *ReadFile;

  ReadFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");

  if(NULL == ReadFile)
    {
      printf("\n file did not open \n");
      return 1;
    }

  fseek(ReadFile, 0 , SEEK_END);      
  int size = ftell(ReadFile);         
  rewind(ReadFile);                   

  char *content = calloc( size +1, 1); 

  fread(content,1,size,ReadFile);     

  /*fclose(ReadFile); */              

  printf("you made it past opening and reading file\n");
  printf("your file size is %i\n",size);

  /******************************************************************/


  /*********************String compare and print*********************/
  int count =0;
  int inputs;

  for( inputs = 2; inputs < argc ; inputs++)
    { 
  char *input = argv[inputs];


  while (content = strstr(content,"a"))
    {
      count++;
      content++;
  }
  printf("Your count is:%i\n",count);

  }
  /*****************************************************************/
    return 0;
}
```

Alright so I changed my compare portion a bit from 'a' to input because I want to be able to compare any number character substrings I input into the terminal:

```
    /*********************String compare and print*********************/
  int count =0;
  int inputs;

  for( inputs = 2; inputs <= argc ; inputs++)
    { 
  char *input = argv[inputs];
  content = input;

  while (content = strstr(content,input))
    {
      count++;
      content++;
  }
  printf("Your count is:%i\n",count);

  }
  /*****************************************************************/
```

but now my output is:
( my bar text file has 'aabbcc' in it)

```
$ gcc strstrTest.c
$ ./a.out bar a a
you made it past opening and reading file
your file size is 7
Your count is:1
Your count is:2
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Compile with `gcc -Wall -g ststrTest.c -o mytest`; run `./mytest` and debug it with `gdb`

Comment: I tried but I got a warning in the while loop: 'suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]' and when I tried ./mytest the file did not open

Comment: Improve the code till you got no warnings. Then replace `./a.out` by `./mytest` in the command you are running, e.g. run `./mytest bar a a` or even learn how to use `gdb` (start with `gdb ./mytest` ...)

Comment: Any idea how to fix the warning: 'warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]' I think it's referring to the while statement line

Comment: Code `while ((content = strstr(content,input)))` or `while ((content = strstr(content,input))) != NULL)`

Comment: That fixed my warning thanks, but now output is counting 1 on the first iteration and then 2 for the second when I try ./mytest bar a a

Comment: **use the `gdb` debugger**

Comment: Alright when I input the command it tells me 'bar is not a core dump: File format not recognized' . I'll try to read up on how to use gdb.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, [`strstr`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strstr) returns `NULL`, because it doesn't find any more `a`'s. When you try to `strstr` one more, it tries to search NULL, which gives the segmentation fault.

Maybe you wanted to do

```
content = strstr(input, "a");
```

or

```
content = input;
```

before the while loop or something similar.

*Update:*

Somehow, I completely missed, that `bar` is a file name. So, if you want to search this file for multiple strings, you must simply let `content` alone, use a different variable for searching and reset this every time you search for another string

```
for (inputs = 2; inputs < argc; inputs++) { 
    char *input = argv[inputs];
    char *search = content;

    while (search = strstr(search, input)) {
        count++;
        search++;
    }

    printf("Your count is:%i\n", count);
}
```

Comment: From the original Linux man-page sources: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strstr.3.html

Comment: you code needs to reset count also per loop unless the count is total

Comment: @user1281385 Actually, I don't know what OP's intent is. But thank you for spotting, I didn't think of that.